# Jquery in Wordpress Gutenberg Block not firing on edit screen

Tags: jquery, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

I've got a google map rendering in a Gutenberg custom block - works fine on the front end page, doesn't trigger when editing at all.

This is the offending bit of javascript with in the php block render function

```
var xml_url="http://localhost/thegatewaychurch/?ca_download=address-xml&member_type_id=1,3&small_group=NULL&address-xml=7627e5c158"; 
var lat=52.75279627903644; 
var lng=0.418583437048369; 
var zoom=12;
jQuery(document).ready(function(){load(lat,lng,xml_url,zoom);});
```

I'm guessing "document" needs to be something else. The Javascript file with load() is in the header.

Comment: I've discovered block editor assets have their own hook 'enqueue_block_assets', but even that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on the front end because it is nothing to do with gutenberg blocks, you are just running jquery on document load. If you remove the custom block and enqueue the code directly, it will still work.

Probably you are not mounting your jquery element onto block properly in the custom block properly. Check your load function.

You are waiting for the document being loaded,so it is not important your load function is in the header section or before the closing body tag.